# Extract $A+B+C$ from $A^{\frac{3}{2}}+B^{\frac{3}{2}}+C^{\frac{3}{2}}= R*D^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: power-series

I need to find **$A+B+C=?$** from $A^{\frac{3}{2}}+B^{\frac{3}{2}}+C^{\frac{3}{2}}= R*D^{\frac{3}{2}}$

I know that I can't use log for this equation.

Do anyone have any ideas of how to do the extraction??

Thanks

Comment: Are $A,B,C,D,R$ restricted to be integers, positive integers, or what restrictions are there on them if any?

Comment: They are all positive integers

Comment: Also it seems you want to have $R,D$ be the same for all cases and are viewing $A,B,C$ as variables. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. I just want to know the expression for A+B+C=.....................

Comment: I don't know how to remove the "power"

Comment: Iredi: By your last comment do you mean you do *not* want the $3/2$ to be a power in the equation? [Why would you want to "remove" it?] Or is the last comment referring to your wanting to find a valid math technique to remove the powers? If that's is, there is none which works over sums of separate terms. (See my answer below, I think your equation does not allow determination of the sum A+B+C.)

Answer (score 2):

In one solution let $A=1,B=144,C=289,$ and in the other let $A=81,B=100,C=289.$ In both cases let $R=246$ and $D=9.$ For both cases then your equation holds, yet for the first one $A+B+C=434$ and for the second one $A+B+C=470.$ So the sum cannot be determined.